# How do you change a URL in the address bar while loading the page?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

Like when you click this `<a href='http://www.mysite.com/page.php?v=foo&z=bar'>`

And then when the page has finished loading, the URL in the address bar should be shown like this `http://www.mysite.com/page.php` without the query.

it's like when you try to sign in to a webmail for example, you enter username and password, they use query strings right? but when the page has finished loading, the URL without any query.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? If it's sensitive data, it shouldn't be used in a query string.

Comment: The URL shows the location the user is visiting. If you want to change it, you need to redirect to a new location.

Comment: it's like when you try to sign in to a webmail for example, they use query strings, but when the page has finished loading, the URL without any query

Comment: @webbiedave: redirecting? so it cannot be done without redirecting?

Comment: Good caching + observer github.com and the new youtube.com

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when we change the URL of the address bar then web browser fires request without refreshing the page i.e. 204 i guess.

If you dont want the elements to be displayed in the URL user the HTML form with the post method

```
<form action="page.url" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="param_name" value="value"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can change the URL without reloading the page is by changing what is located `after` an `#` character.

Anything that changes before it will cause a page reloading.

Comment: **with** loading, how do you do that?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it? whats the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy that you could employ... I don't think it's really great from a UX standpoint but it accomplishes your goal:

1. Process query string parameters on first load and store them in the session array (`$_SESSION`)
2. Redirect to the same page w/out query string parameters
3. Do whatever it is you need to do with the parameter values that are now stored in `$_SESSION`

Like I said, I don't think this is a spectacular approach and it's wrought with potential side effects that you will have to handle in code, which doesn't seem worth the pain. Also, even with this approach the URL that includes the query string parameters will appear in the client's browsing history, so you aren't really hiding anything in the end (assuming that's your goal).

Another approach to consider would be using the POST method rather than the GET method for your request. You'd simply pass the parameters as the payload of the request rather than on the query string.

Comment: I don't think storing to session and redirecting would be a good idea, because I tried it and the page re-load after the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is by using htaccess.
This file is normaly on the root of your website along with the index file.

Your htaccess file must start with:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

And then all you need to do is (for the example you used):

```
RewriteRule ^page.php page.php?v=$1&z=$2
```

For more information about htaccess: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php

Answer (score 0):

See `HTML5's pushState` and use it with content loaded using AJAX.
BEware that this can be quite complicated to maintain and is not supported by all but the latest browsers.

example of a site using it :http://www.shopify.com/tour/website-design